# Issue with building a release apk of react native with assembleRelease command

Tags: android, react-native, aapt

I have a release native application where I have

1. target SDK:31
2. compile SDK:31
3. build tools version: 30.0.2

Now, I have one library installed as 'react-native-secure-storage'. The issue is when I hit ./gradlew assembleRelease it always throws error as below:

> Execution failed for task ':react-native-secure-storage:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

but it works fine when I create a build with ./gradlew app:assembleRelease it gets successfully build or else from Android Studion menu>build apk: it is getting successfully built.